# Method to store data until browser is closed

Tags: javascript, session

is there any method (using JavaScript) how to store session until browser is closed? I wanted to use session cookie - when *expires* is not set the cookie is supposed to expire when browser is closed. But for any practical purpose this is not usable because Firefox with *Show my windows and tabs from last time* option does not clear session cookies even after browser is closed.

I also cannot use *onunload* or *onbeforeunload* because I need to remember the data until the browser is closed even when users reloads or goes to some other page and then comes back.

Comment: If a browser does not close the session, you can't do anything against it.

Comment: with me as user the session would not expire.

Comment: The crux of the problem here, unfortunately, is Firefox's handling of session cookies. That said, unless *show my windows and tabs* is the default option for Firefox these days, perhaps you should consider that an edge case? In the end, of course, it depends who your end users are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage), `localStorage`'s little-known cousin. It should do exactly what you need--store variables in a session and clear them when the session is ended.

Comment: This is valuable information, but I have to wonder whether the browsers govern the lifecycle of sessionStorage objects the exact same way it deals with cookies, which would result in the same problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @Pointy: "A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated." It seems like the OP should be fine with `sessionStorage`. I can't say for sure, though.

Comment: I agree that it *should* work, but (for example) Firefox is pretty loose with what "browser session" means, what with the ability to restore things after a crash.

Comment: Thank you - the problem is that when Firefox with multiple tabs is closed and reopened it still remembers the session. I would consider this behaviour a bug but apparently Mozilla people want Firefox to behave that way. If anyone knows about a workaround please let me know.